# Execute a cron job on the first working day of the month inside crontab on Ubuntu 20

Tags: ubuntu, automation, cron, ubuntu-20.04

I am looking for a way to execute a cron job on the **first working day** of the month.

I have attempted using `1W`, however that is invalid on Ubuntu at the very least.

```
grep crontab /var/log/syslog
Jul 27 14:32:01 ip-10-82-2-89 cron[475]: (*system*staging) ERROR (Syntax error, this crontab file will be ignored)
```

```
# Run the report on the first working day of every month
30 8 1W * * www-data /var/www/registration/bin/console appbundle:stadium:visitspermonth --env=staging 2>&1 >>/var/log/registration/visitspermonth.log
```

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

Edit 2:

Try this instead:
`30 8 */40 * 1-5`

It should run at 08:30 on every 40th day-of-month if it's on every day-of-week from Monday through Friday.
(https://crontab.guru/#30_8_*/40_*_1-5)

Plus:
`30 8 2-3 * * [ "$(date '+%u')" = "1" ]`
It should run at 08:30 on every day-of-month from 2 through 3 if it's Monday

You will need to add your command as well. Should look similar to this:
`30 8 2-3 * * [ "$(date '+\%u')" == "1" ] && www-data /var/www/registration/bin/console appbundle:stadium:visitspermonth --env=staging 2>&1 >>/var/log/registration/visitspermonth.log`

Comment: I don't think this is right. This would run the command on the first to seventh of each month, as well as on every Monday

Comment: Sorry, I made a very big edit.